# springmvc and tiles are used in following program

Tags: spring-mvc, tiles

Below is the spring mvc program. Problem is whenever I fill mailid and password then instead of home page, relogin page pops up even though that mailid and password is present in database.
 It has controller,daos,user and few views(home,relogin,registered),tiles.xml,ds-servlet.xml,web.xml.
 In authenticate method home and relogin is present ,always relogin displayed although mailid and password is present in database.

```
usercontroller.java
                                                                                                  package controllers;

           import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

            import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
              import org.springframework.stereotype.*;
              import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

               import daos.UserDao;
               import models.User;

    @Controller
    public class Usercontroller {
        @Autowired
        UserDao dao;
        @Autowired
        HttpSession session;
        @RequestMapping("/regform.spr")
        public String register(
            @ModelAttribute User user) throws Exception
        {

        dao.save(user);
        return "registered";
    }
    @RequestMapping("/login.spr")
    public String authenticate(
        @ModelAttribute User user)
    {
        String str="relogin";
        try
        {
            if(dao.findUser(user))
            {
            str="home";
            session.setAttribute("user",user);
            }

        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);

        }
        return str;
    }
```

save method is working properly but problem comes in finduser

```
userdao.java


    package daos;

    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;

    import javax.sql.DataSource;

    import models.User;

    public class UserDao {

        private DataSource dataSource;




        public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
            this.dataSource = dataSource;
        }




        public void save(User user) throws Exception
        {
            Connection con=dataSource.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement("insert into UserMaster (name,mailId,password) values(?,?,?)");

            stmt.setString(1, user.getName());
            stmt.setString(2, user.getMailId());
            stmt.setString(3, user.getPassword());
            stmt.executeUpdate();
            stmt.close();

        }
        public boolean findUser(User user) throws Exception
        {
            boolean flag=false;
            //Connection is obtained
            Connection con=dataSource.getConnection();
            //P.S. is created for the insert query
            PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement(
            "select id,name from UserMaster where mailId=? and password=?");
            //param values are set in the query
            stmt.setString(1, user.getMailId());
            stmt.setString(2, user.getPassword());
            //query is executed.
            ResultSet rset=stmt.executeQuery();
            if(rset.next())
            {
                flag=true;
                //id & name are loaded into the object
                user.setId(rset.getInt(1));
                user.setName(rset.getString(2));
            }
            //connection is closed.
            con.close();
          return flag;
        }
    }
```

Here is the home and relogin views

```
home.jsp

    <div class="jumbotron">
    <h3>welcome java-ians!! lets get started.</h3>
    <p>Welcome, <b>${user.name}</b></p>
    <h4>click to move forward!!</h4>
    <button class="btn btn-info">forward</button>
    </div>"


relogin.jsp

    <div >
    <h1>emailid or password is incorrect</h1>
    <jsp:include page="login.jsp"></jsp:include>
    </div>
```

tiles.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
     <!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC 
     "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.0//EN" 
     "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_0.dtd"> 

      <tiles-definitions>



       <definition name="registered" template="/views/registered.jsp"> 
        <put-attribute name="title" value="registered"/>
        <put-attribute name="contents" value="/views/registered.jsp"/> 
        </definition>

        <definition name="home" template="/views/home.jsp"> 
         <put-attribute name="contents" value="/views/home.jsp"/  
         </definition>

         <definition name="relogin" template="/views/relogin.jsp"> 
         <put-attribute name="title" value="relogin"/>
         <put-attribute name="contents" value="/views/relogin.jsp"/> 
         </definition>

          </tiles-definitions>
```

Comment: This is too broad that nobody can help you. Please do some research by yourself and ask a specific question.

Comment: sir please see usercontroller.java and dao..remaining are useless.in usercontroller there is authenticate method only relogin is returned not home